# When would a query result be non-scalar?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm reading [MySQL's documentation on the assignment operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/assignment-operators.html), and in the section for the `:=` operator, it says

> The value on the right hand side may be a literal value, another variable storing a value, or any legal expression that yields a scalar value, including the result of a query (provided that this value is a scalar value).

If I understand correctly, a scalar value is a value that represents a fixed value instead of a range or collection of values or an object.

Being very new to SQL in general, I don't quite understand the parenthetical statement at the end of the quote. When would the result of a query be a non-scalar value? Is it when a query simply returns multiple columns from a row in its result? If so, how can those results be used meaningfully in a MySQL script if they can't be stored in a variable?

Comment: (provided that this value is a scalar value) = ( will allowed if a one row / one col result set occurs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A scalar value has one column and one row. You can't assign such multi-valued results to a MySQL session variable.

But you can assign multiple columns to multiple variables.

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM mytable INTO @varA, @varB, @varC;
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html for more details.

Answer (score 5):

Such a query is a *scalar* subquery.  Such a subquery has two important properties:

- The subquery returns exactly one column.
- The subquery returns at most one row.

If the subquery returns no rows, then the assigned value is `NULL`.

That is a *subquery*.  You can assign multiple values using `SELECT` and `:=`:

```
select @var1 := col1, @val2 := col2
from . . .;
```